# Python: How to append a file in python using inputs?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python, and have been trying to create a program where I create a file from user inputs. However, I cannot seem to get it to work, and keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "my_program.py", line 7, in <module>
        my_file.append(x)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I think this means that I cannot append the file, but I am not sure at all why. Here is the relevant part of my program:

```
my_file = "my_file"
with open(my_file, 'a') as my_file:
    lines = True
    counting_variable = 0
    while lines:
        x = input()
        my_file.append(x)
```

Thank you very much for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already opening the file in append mode i.e `open(my_file, 'a')`, just `write()` will append your inputs.

```
my_file = "my_file"
with open(my_file, 'a') as my_file:
    lines = True
    counting_variable = 0
    while lines:
        x = input()
        my_file.write(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not able to comment yet (anyone mind converting?), but I think there are quite a few questions similar to this on SO. Try [Python Append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

use `my_file.write(x)` because `my_file.append()` is not a valid syntax.